# calling javascript function before asp mvc controller fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i need to fire javascript code before controller redirect to an other view
here is my view code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "register", "Home",null,new{@class= "submit"})
```

my cotroller code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult register()
    {

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

my javascript code

```
$(function () {
$('.submit').click(function () { $(".anyButton").addClass("c")}); });
```

this is little example of what i want to do in javascript as i added an animation 
my Question is how to run javascript code bafore action in controller run and redirct me to other view

Comment: You wont be able to do this. My suggestion would be creating an AJAX register, which returns a true or a false to the browser depending on if it was successful, and then redirect it through javascript if the register result is 1. ie. `$.ajax({url: '/register', data: {someFormData: 'here'}, success: function(res) { if ( res == 1 ) { /* Do animation here */ document.location = '/redirectindex' }});`

Comment: so how could i send data that i recieved in controller to js to check on it??
i'm little bit confused

Answer (score -1):

You need to stop the default behavior of acnhor tag, execute the code you want to and then redirect using javascript code after that like:

```
$(function () {
     $('.submit').click(function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault(); // stop redirection
                  $(".anyButton").addClass("c")
                  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href"); // redirect now
         }); 
 });
```

Comment: But then how is the register page ever going to get the information?

Comment: the question is about executing js code before redirection, so this is the one way

Comment: thanks, but my question is how to excute js before controller in general 
as there will be data send in controller

Comment: for that we can have a form and after execuing js, submit the form via js

Comment: sorry but can i submit a form from js?
sorry but i'm new with asp and i never submitted i form from js

Comment: yes just search, how to submit form using jquery/javascript

Answer (score -1):

you can return false to stop forwarding link like the following

```
$(function () {
     $('.submit').click(function (e) {
                  $(".anyButton").addClass("c");
                  return false;
         }); 
 });
```

hope this help you